# StreamWriter cannot find part of Path

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am using a Falcon X3 mobile computer on vs 2008.  I am trying to write a text file to the local directory.

a) Is this possible?

b) It throws an error " could not find a part of the path".

**Here is my code:**

```
 var output = new List<string>();

var importDirectory = string.Format(@"C:\Temp");

var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");

var fileName = string.Format("Test_{0}.txt", timeStamp);

var path = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", importDirectory, fileName);

output.Add("01");

output.Add(path);

 var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path);

streamWriter.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

Please can any one suggest me code or solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the "Falcon X3" but does it have a "C:\TEMP" ? You should be able to verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows CE devices don't have a "C:\" directory. The root directory is "\", so your path should be "\Temp". However for best practices I would not get in the habit of storing files in your root directory, instead use Environment.GetFolderPath(...) to get the path of your user's personal folder (My Documents) or the application data folder for you application.